# How to convert to Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-comprehension

```
ls = ['abc', 56, 49, 63, 66, 80]
for i in ls:
    if(isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float)):
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            ls[i] = str(ls[i])
```

May I know how to create the list comprehension of above code?

I am trying  the following but not working

```
if (s for s in ls isinstance(s, int) or isinstance(s, float)):
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        ls[i] = str(ls[i])
```

Comment: Is it intended that the last number replaced all the items in the list?

Comment: Just a randomly example, a mixture of number and string. It can be float too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your example where you have either strings or integers or floats, you can use a simple list comprehension:

```
ls = ['abc', 56, 49, 63, 66, 80]
print([str(l) for l in ls])
```

Or alternatively, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(list(map(str, ls)))
```

If you only want to convert floats and integers to strings (and ignore anything else like booleans, decimal objects, etc.):

```
print([str(l) if isinstance(l, int) or isinstance(l, float) else l for l in ls])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! 

I am trying to convert list items to string only if I found it in the list but I think it's good to just convert it to string while looping.

Comment: note that you don't need to use `or` with `isinstance`; `isinstance` also accepts a tuple (so `(int, float)`), additionally this wouldn't filter out *`bool`s*, as `bool` is a subclass of `int`.